# Circle In Rectangle Packing Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, computational-geometry

I need a packing algorithm that fits a set of circles of varying radii, if the circles fit, in  a rectangle.  I've seen various pages on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) and other sites, but the implementation itself is either too complicated or simply a mathematical theorem, neither of which I have the experience or knowledge to utilize.

Someone asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927380/maximum-packing-of-rectangles-in-a-circle), which is sort of the inverse--I need circles in rectangles not vice versa, and I would prefer Java, not MATLAB, though I suppose if necessary I could port it.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I don't need to find the smallest rectangle in which the circles would fit, I just need to know *if* the circles would fit within a given rectangle with specified dimensions.

Comment: You could use a genetic algorithm which are always pretty simple to write, it depends on your goal if this is the correct approach though.

Comment: There's this: http://goo.gl/wrxXV, though I should say (and update the question) that I don't need to find the smallest rectangle or anything, I need to figure out _IF_ a given set of circles fit within a specified rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google: algorithm, pack circles in rectangle
http://www.jstor.org/stable/4102107
Shows up right underneath this stack overflow question.
The jstor.org paper spells out a greedy circles in rectangle packing algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is appears heavily related to bin packing and so I suspect it is NP-hard. So unfortunately I don't think there's a good algorithm for solving this efficiently (aka non-brute force).

I don't even think there's a good, simple, greedy way of approaching it.

There have been many research papers written on the subject though if you have access to them. Here is one: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221707004274